# What are these earthly things and heavenly things in John 3:12

Tags: john

> John 3:6 Flesh gives birth to flesh, but the Spirit gives birth to spirit.
>
> John 3:12 I have spoken to you of earthly things and you do not believe; how then will you believe if I speak of heavenly things?

Isn't spiritual birth a heavenly thing?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the context, it seems that "earthly things" refer to what take place on earth and what have been revealed and thus are expected to be known especially by teachers of Israel whereas "heavenly things" are what take place in heaven and what have not been revealed and thus are not expected to be known (cf. Wis 9:16-18).

Notice vv. 10–11:

> 10 Jesus answered him, “Are you a teacher of Israel, and yet you do not understand these things? 11 “Very truly, I tell you, we speak of what we know and testify to what we have seen; yet you do not receive our testimony. (NRSV)

Jesus expects this teacher of Israel to understand what he is teaching. To which kind of "rebirth" does Jesus expect this teacher of Israel to understand? Jesus could be referring to the new life that God's spirit gives as spoken of in the scriptures: e.g., ezek 36:26; 37:9-10; Isa 44:3–5. Jesus could also be referring to the new life of conversion as understood in Jewish tradition. In the rabbinic literature conversion to Judaism is spoken of as a new birth: e.g., https://www.sefaria.org/Yevamot.22a.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en; https://www.sefaria.org/Yevamot.62a.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en. Notice Jesus says in v. 5 "Very truly, I tell you, no one can enter the kingdom of God without being born of water and Spirit" (NRSV). The water seems to be in reference to immersion in the conversion process. (Also, perhaps "the will of man" in John 1:13 refers to conversion.)

Also consider v. 13:

> No one has ascended into heaven except the one who descended from heaven, the Son of Man.

Jesus seems to be alluding to Deut 30:11–14 and Prov 30:4 as well as to Jewish legends of the late Second Temple Period that Enoch (e.g., 1 Enoch), Moses (e.g., Targum Ps 68:19), and other prominent figures are said to have ascended to heaven to learn and reveal heavenly things. The heavenly things that Nicodemus would not be expected to know are what is in heaven, the things that certain figures were said to have learned and then revealed by ascending to (and descending from) heaven. But Jesus is saying that no one has done this. The one capable of revealing heavenly things is the Son of Man who descended from heaven.

Answer (score 1):

Earthly things speak of his miracles that were to draw attention to who Jesus was and who sent him. The leaders didn't believe and repent of their abuse of power over the people - they abused the privileges of authority by 'lording it over the people'.

> John 10:38 But if I do them, even though you do not believe me,
> believe the works, that you may know and understand that the Father is
> in me, and I in the Father."

They would not believe, choosing their own ways instead of what Jesus offered.

He offered heavenly things like true life but they were unable to begin to comprehend. God had not yet opened their hearts to want to understand, to follow, to learn, to trust. They trusted in the position they had and the place of fragile power they had under Roman rule.

Knowing who Jesus was, as the son of God, (a heavenly thing) troubled their hard hearts and closed minds making them angry and wanting to kill the saviour - let alone do as he said - repent and be baptised. This process would unlock a growth and understanding that earthly things never could.

You asked, **Isn't spiritual birth a heavenly thing?**

We're told Jesus was re born of the spirit when resurrected.

...having been put to death in the flesh, but made alive in the spirit. 1 Pet 3:18

Flesh and blood cannot enter the kingdom, so to enter we must be **not** flesh and blood but re born 'from above', as Jesus puts it to Nicodemus, in the spirit. This happens when we too are resurrected.

Our spiritual birth is from God not men, certainly not baptism which, significant though it is, is just a symbol to share in the new life that is beginning - as Jesus was raised from the dead by his God, we share in his life and the means by which he obtained it.

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify by what you mean by "heavenly".

Spiritual birth is not of this world and that becomes apparent throughout the entirety of this passage. Jesus is speaking of one thing and Nicodemus of another. Nicodemus is a Pharisee, he was an expert in the understanding of the Law.

I think that in this passage context is of paramount importance and indeed gives light to meaning. Jesus was/is the Messiah sent to FULFILL the Law, the arrival of Jesus marked the end of one dispensation and the start of another. Before Jesus you were *saved* through the LAW however you still could not enter the Kingdom, Jesus signified a change in that you could now become *saved* through grace and could enter the Kingdom. In this passage however he places emphasis on what that means, spiritual birth.

When we are born (physically), we enter the WORLD in sin and we become part of the world (Romans 5). Only once we undergo a Spiritual birth are we taken OUT of the world and *re-birthed*. The typology of this can be found throughout the Bible. This same typology is seen with the birth of Jesus. When Jesus returned from Egypt after Joseph and Mary fled from the cruel Herod, Jesus fulfilled the prophecy of Hosea 11 "out of Egypt I called My son".

This same typology is also found in Exodus. The Israelites were taken out of Egypt, washed clean in the Jordan river and passed into the promised land. The same with spiritual birth, we are taken out of the world (represented by Egypt), washed clean by the Spirit (the water) and we are allowed into the Kingdom (promised land). That is what Jesus was saying in this passage.

Something which is also important to understand is that there is NOTHING we as humans can do to enter into the Kingdom, we cannot atone for our own sins and no offering we make will ever be sufficient. That is why Jesus was able to fulfill the Law, his life was the FINAL offering that atoned for ALL man's sin (2 Corinthians 5:15). He completed the Law, thereby ending that dispensation.That is the beauty of it all, we do not need to make offerings in the temple we can be saved through the spirit, we can be re-birthed into the Kingdom and become part thereof through the Grace of God.